# Sitecore requests give a 404 in connected mode

Tags: jss, react

I'm using Sitecore 10.1 with JSS 16.0.0. In connected mode when I visit a Sitecore path, it gives a 404 error.

For example:-

http://localhost:3000/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=%2F&sc_lang=en&sc_apikey=%3D4F3181-E8CF-49E9-9783-00605AF39941%7D

[image]

Based on `setupProxy.js`, it should be proxied:

```
app.use(proxy('/sitecore', { target: config.sitecoreApiHost }));
```

Does anybody know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research I found the following PR: https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/pull/808

It seems this was a bug and fixed in JSS 19.0.0.

If you're on an older version you should update your `setupProxy.js` to this:

```
// when in connected mode we want to proxy Sitecore paths
// off to Sitecore

app.use(proxy('/sitecore', { target: config.sitecoreApiHost, changeOrigin: true }));
// media items
app.use(proxy('/-', { target: config.sitecoreApiHost, changeOrigin: true }));
// visitor identification
app.use(proxy('/layouts', { target: config.sitecoreApiHost, changeOrigin: true }));
```

After this the request worked instead of a 404:

[image]